# Loading all objects of a dictionary from a pickle file

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, dictionary, pickle

I have my program setup so it takes user input and creates an object from it. Then the object is stored in a dictionary, which in turn is pickled to a .pkl file. Any new object written to this file uses this code:

```
def save_object(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, 'ab') as output:
        pickle.dump(obj, output, -1)
```

Now when i i re-open the program i need to load the entire contents of my dictionary which i attempt to do with this:

```
self.load_file = open("Obj_file.pkl", 'rb+')
self.employee_dict = pickle.load(self.load_file)
print self.employee_dict
```

Now from my understanding this will load the first two objects only, and this is actually the outcome im seeing when the code is ran. It just opens the first two objects. How can i load the entire dictionary, this seems like it is rather difficult given the research i've done. Also, its essential to my program that i use a dictionary because objects will be deleted from it and i need order to remain the same after such a process is performed.

Comment: dicts don't have any order, if you want order use a list

Comment: I know, what i meant was i create my keys sequentially e.g. if i have objects 1 - 3 and i delete key 2 i want the other keys to remain the same which they will. Sorry if that was unclear

Comment: are you storing many dicts or just one?

Comment: I'm only storing one.

Comment: where is the issue then, if you are only pickling and loading a single dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened your pickle file in *append mode*; this writes a *new* pickle record at the end of the file, leaving your first version at the start.

Then, when you read the pickle from the file when you re-open the program, you only read that very first version.

For your needs, it is far simpler to open the file in *write* mode, replacing all the contents with the new version of your dictionary each time:

```
def save_object(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(obj, output, -1)
```

Comment: Yes, i see, when i open in write mode though every time i create a new object upon re-opening my script it over-writes the previous .pkl and i lose the objects stored.

Comment: @After_Sunset: but what you write to the pickle should be *your whole state*. So if you have a dictionary, *add to that dictionary*, then write the new version of that dictionary to the file.

Comment: @After_Sunset: in other words: your file contains an older *version* of your dictionary. Your program has now modified that dictionary, so you want to *replace* the version in the file with your new version.

Comment: I understand what your saying but, i believe my code is already set up that way. When i save the new version it just over-writes the old one. It doesn't seem to add just over-write.

Comment: @After_Sunset: no, your original code uses `ab`, or binary append mode. That writes the pickle data *after* the current pickle data. The `pickle` module will only read the first record, ignoring any data following.

Comment: okay , i believe i figured out the issue. I think i was resetting the dict to be empty everytime i __init__ the script. Thank you for your time and help : )